# The parameterized query expects the parameter , which was not supplied

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

in my MVC application there is a method

```
public void insertAddress(AddressModel address)
{
        var connection = OpenConnection();
        var command = connection.CreateCommand();
        command.CommandText = "insert into Adres (AddressLine_1,AddressLine_2,Postcode,Town,DateMovedIn,Id) values (@AddressLine_1, @AddressLine_2, @Postcode, @Town,@DateMovedIn,@Id)";
        AddParameterString(command, "@AddressLine_1", address.AddressLine_1);
        AddParameterString(command, "@AddressLine_2", address.AddressLine_2);
        AddParameterString(command, "@Postcode", address.Postcode);
        AddParameterString(command, "@Town", address.Town);
        AddParameterString(command, "@DateMovedIn", address.DateMovedIn.ToString("yyyyMMdd"));
        AddParameterInt(command, "@Id", address.Id);

        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

`AddressLine2` in model is not required. When user is not submitting `AddressLine2` I get error:

> The parameterized query '(@AddressLine_1 nvarchar(3),@AddressLine_2
>   nvarchar(4000),@Postc' expects the parameter '@AddressLine_2', which
>   was not supplied.

How can I modify this method to work in both cases - user submitting `AddressLine2` and user not submitting `AddressLine2`?

Comment: Can you please show the definition of `AddParameterString` method? Why not just use `ParameterCollection` instead? And don't store your `DateTime` values as a string for your `DateMovedIn` column. Change it to `datetime2` type instead.

Comment: Pass in `null` when not supplied (assuming the underlying database has a column that supports `null`: which it should do if it is optional).

Comment: try address.AddressLine_2 ?? DBNull.Value, or something like this

Comment: you may use ternary operator to solve this problem..  [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public void insertAddress(AddressModel address)
{
    var connection = OpenConnection();
    var command = connection.CreateCommand();
    command.CommandText = "insert into Adres (AddressLine_1,AddressLine_2,Postcode,Town,DateMovedIn,Id) values (@AddressLine_1, @AddressLine_2, @Postcode, @Town,@DateMovedIn,@Id)";
    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@AddressLine_1", Value = address.AddressLine_1 });
    if (address.AddressLine_2 == null)
    {
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@AddressLine_2", Value = DBNull.Value });
    }
    else
    {
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@AddressLine_2", Value = address.AddressLine_2 });
    }
    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@Postcode", Value = address.Postcode });
    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@Town", Value = address.Town });
    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@DateMovedIn", Value = address.DateMovedIn.ToString("yyyyMMdd") });
    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@Id", Value = address.Id });
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This happens when a parameter value is null. To fix it you need to set parameter value to DbNull when the property is null.

```
void AddParameterString(SqlCommand command, string parameterName, string parameterValue)
{
     var param = command.Parameters.Add(parameterName, SqlDbType.NVarChar, 4000);
     param.Value = String.IsNullOrEmpty(parameterValue) ? (object) DbNull.Value : (object) parameterValue;

}
```

Comment: @ Gene R Many thanks for help, I don't know whether it is the best option but I used Gene R solution and it is working very well.

Comment: Set Parameter property `IsNullable = true` would indicate to the parser that the parameter may be null, and would stop it complaining of such

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use Null-coalescing operator (??):

```
AddParameterString(command, "@AddressLine_2", address.AddressLine_2 ?? Convert.DBNull);
```